# EF Core 2.1 Identity tables empty after HasData() seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to seed my Identity tables with the EF Core 2.1 HasData pattern, the code executes but nothing is inserted into the tables.
My DBContext class code:

```
public partial class IdentityDBContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public IdentityDBContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        IdentityRole RootRole = new IdentityRole 
        { 
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            Name = IdentityDBContext.RoleTypes.RootAdmin, 
            NormalizedName = "Root Admin" 
        };
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(RootRole);

        IdentityUser AdminUser = new IdentityUser 
        { 
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            UserName = "m@soze.biz", 
            Email = "m@soze.biz", 
            NormalizedUserName = "m@soze.biz".ToUpper(), 
            NormalizedEmail = "m@soze.biz".ToUpper(), 
            EmailConfirmed = true 
        };
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(AdminUser);

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string> 
        { 
            UserId = AdminUser.Id, 
            RoleId = RootRole.Id 
        });
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs in the Configure method I have:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var IdentityContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdentityDBContext>();
    IdentityContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

I can step through the `OnModelCreating` code executing without an exception however no records are added to the tables, both `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles` are empty.

Any suggestions on why this isn't working?

Comment: Did you create a new EF migration, after adding the has data code?

Comment: I did try adding a migration after adding the HasData code but it seems I didn't rerun the application to push that migration out. I knew it was something simple I was missing, Thanks Aman! In case anyone else comes across this and has the same issue, in the package manager I ran 'Add-Migration Update-Database -Context IdentityDBContext' then executed the app and the migrations were pushed to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

For your issue, it is caused that `Migrate` only applied the pending migrations, it would not detect the changes after you change `IdentityDBContext`.

When you create project with `Identity`, it will automatically create the first migrations, and then even through, you changed `IdentityDBContext`, `Migrate` will only apply the first migrations without your other operations.

Here are two options for you:

- For first initialize the database, you could try code below which will seed the data.

  ```
          using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
      {
          var IdentityContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
          IdentityContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
      }
  ```
- The second option is that you already tried. Before run `Migrate`, run `Add-Migration` to generate the migrations for new changes.

Answer (score 1):

As per Tao's answer, if you created the project with the visual studio template and added authentication as an option there, the migrations will already have been added.
The "HasData" method isn't executed during the "Update-Database" phase, it is executed during the "Add-Migration" phase and added into your migration. 
You need to delete the "Migrations" folder, and then run "Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema" in the package command window inorder for your seed data to get applied to the migration.
Update-Database will then seed your data from the new migration.
This drove me crazy for 3 hours one Sunday.